# npm install fails while eslint dependency cannot be solved

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, npm-install, okta

When I run npm install on a sample project I get the result below

```
npm install

> @okta/samples-js-vue@0.1.0 postinstall D:\home\projects\trunk\projects\VoiceToText\samples-js-vue
> npm run install-custom-login && npm run install-okta-hosted-login


> @okta/samples-js-vue@0.1.0 install-custom-login D:\home\projects\trunk\projects\VoiceToText\samples-js-vue
> cd custom-login && npm install --allow-root

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 9983 packages in 11.244s
found 554 vulnerabilities (3 low, 14 moderate, 536 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> @okta/samples-js-vue@0.1.0 install-okta-hosted-login D:\home\projects\trunk\projects\VoiceToText\samples-js-vue
> cd okta-hosted-login && npm install

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 9864 packages in 11.739s
found 551 vulnerabilities (3 low, 14 moderate, 533 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
npm WARN eslint-plugin-eslint-plugin@2.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 2069 packages in 35.602s
```

I then ran >npm audit fix
and got :

```
npm WARN eslint-plugin-eslint-plugin@2.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I've tried installing eslint and eslint-plugin-eslint-plugin but I get the same problem.
Is this an accepted warning?

/D

Comment: This is accepted one

Comment: can you show us your package.json?